# MIPS Code For conversion of string of characters to base 10 from base 33

Tags: string, mips, radix, review

I have this assignment and it has to do all of the following:

I have to: write a MIPS program that reads a string of up to 4 characters from user input. The program must process the user input with a loop. The program must NOT have subprograms. Then, assume that the user input is in base 33. Convert that to a decimal integer. Please help me. I get errors in my code. Also, I don't know how I would convert the string to an integer to later convert into base 10. I thought I was doing it right, but am confused now.

I wrote my code but it seems to not be working.

Here is my code:

```
.data
Ask:

.asciiz "\n Please Enter 4 Characters\n" 

userInput:  .space 20

Answer:

.asciiz "\n You Entered : \n"

.text 

main:
#addi $t0, 0


li $v0, 4
la $a0, Ask #display question
syscall

li $v0, 8 #get input
la $a0, userInput
li $a1, 20
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, Answer
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, userInput
syscall

lb $s1, 1($a0)  #last digit
lb $s2 2($a0)   #third
lb $s3 3($a0)   #second digit
lb $s4, 4($a0)  #first digit
lb $t0, 0($a0) #checks for \n

addi $t1, $zero, 10 #takes in \n
addi $t7, $zero, 33   #gets value to multiply
addi $s0, $zero, 1089  #gets 33^2
addi $t5, $zero, 97  #gets 64, smaller than ascii code for 'A'
addi $t6, $zero 96  #gets 96, smaller than ascii code for 'a'
addi $t2, $zero, 65  #loads 47 into $t2, smaller than the ascii code for '0'
#addi $t3, $zero,  55


beq $t0, $t1, Label1

Label1:

blt $s1, $t2, L1
blt $s1, $t5, L2
bgt $s1, $t6, L3

L1: 
    addi $s1, $s1, -48  #subtracts 48 from $s1 which is 48 to get int  from 0 to 9 
L2: 
    addi $s1, $s1, -55 #gets values from 10 to 33
L3: 
    addi $s1, $s1, -87  #gets values from 10 to 33 for small caps

blt $s2, $t2, L4
blt $s2, $t5, L5
bge $s2, $t6, L6

L4: 
    addi $s2, $s2, -48
L5: 
    addi $s2, $s2, -55
L6: 
    addi $s2, $s2, -87

blt $s3, $t2, L7
blt $s3, $t5, L8 
bgt $s3, $t6, L9

L7: addi $s3, $s3, -48
L8: addi $s3, $s3, -55
L9: addi $s3, $s3, -87


blt $s4, $t2, L10
blt $s4, $t5, L11
bgt $s4, $t6, L12

L10: 
    addi $s4, $s4, -48
L11: 
    addi $s4, $s4, -55
L12: 
    addi $s4, $s4 , -87

syscall


add $s5, $zero, 0
add $s5,$s5, $s1
mult $s2, $t7
mflo $s2
add $s5, $s5, $s2
mult $s3, $s0
mflo $s3
add $s5, $s5, $s3
mult $s0, $t7
mflo $s0
mult $s4, $s0
mflo $s4
mfhi $s0
add $s5, $s5, $s4
add $s5, $s5, $s0
syscall

#li $v0, 1
#la $a0, $s5

#la $v0, 4 
#lw $a0, s4

#last system call of the program will be very last instruction
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: _"I get errors in my code."_ and _"it seems to not be working."_ are not good problem descriptions. What exactly are the errors, and where exactly do they occur? Also, the code appears to be targeting a simulator like SPIM or MARS, which have fairly decent debugging features built in (e.g. single-stepping, breakpoints, register/memory viewer). What have you done in terms of analyzing the runtime behavior of your code?

Comment: Ok. So basically, it is not an error from mips. What I mean by that is that if I try to convert 12AB to base 33, it is not working. It just keeps it at 12AB. Also, I don't know for sure if the string to int conversion is actually working. Can you please help?

Comment: Alright. Then use the simulator to single-step through the conversion code and verify that the result of each step is what you expect.

Comment: I tried doing that but I am using QTSpim and I don't think it has that feature. Can you please advise me on how to fix/improve my code?

Comment: Sure it does. You can set breakpoints by right-clicking in the code window, and you can single-step with the F10 key.

Comment: Ok. I was not able to solve it. Please help. I can't see why it's not converting my string to int and then to base 10 . I really don't know what to do and I am worried I will blow it up because my instructor only gives 100 or 0.

Answer (score 2):

For starters:

```
lb $s1, 1($a0)  #last digit
lb $s2 2($a0)   #third
lb $s3 3($a0)   #second digit
lb $s4, 4($a0)  #first digit
lb $t0, 0($a0) #checks for \n
```

You have a 4 character string in a0 - lets assume it was types ABCD

So:

```
0($a0) will be A
1($a0) will be B
2($a0) will be C
3($a0) will be D
```

Next assuming s1 is 'A'

```
Label1:

blt $s1, $t2, L1  # 65
blt $s1, $t5, L2  # 97 
bgt $s1, $t6, L3  # 96


L1: 
    addi $s1, $s1, -48  #subtracts 48 from $s1 which is 48 to get int  from 0 to 9 
L2: 
    addi $s1, $s1, -55 #gets values from 10 to 33
L3: 
    addi $s1, $s1, -87  #gets values from 10 to 33 for small caps
```

'A' is 65 so will jump to L2, subtract -55 so not 10, then fall into L3 and subtract 87 to make -77.

If it was '9' (57) instead of 'A' it would go to L1, subtract 48, fall to  L2, subtract 55, fall to L3, subtract 87.

So for each letter, check, something more like this should occur:

```
 L1: 
    addi $s1, $s1, -48  #subtracts 48 from $s1 which is 48 to get int  from 0 to 9 

    j  DoneL13
 L2: 

    addi $s1, $s1, -55 #gets values from 10 to 33
    j  DoneL13
 L3: 
    addi $s1, $s1, -87  #gets values from 10 to 33 for small caps

 DoneL13:
```

Finally you have some sys calls - not sure what they are mean to do do, but am guessing it magically meant to be knowing you want to print the value in s5 ?

Comment: Yeah, I am meant to print that after conversion to base 10. Thanks for help. I am still a bit confused with why I am not getting my conversion right.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I could fix it?

Comment: at the very least you need to update the L1-L3 statements to not run each other ie: L1 should do the L1 stuff and not do L2 etc.